# Have emojis from MS Outlook render properly in iOS

Tags: ios

I notice that when emails are sent to me from Microsoft Outlook that include smilies, the emoji is rendered as a 'J'.  Is this a known issue with a fix or work-around available?

Comment: It's a known issue with the encoding that Microsoft uses on that character. You could contact Microsoft and Apple to suggest they figure out how to fix it, but beyond that, there is no work-around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook uses a non-unicode wingdings font to represent the smiley, instead of the Unicode standard smiley which everyone agreed to use 5 years ago.

Until MS changes its app to conform to the standard, the only fix is to ask the sender of such emails to delete the autocorrect entries in Outlook which replace things like :-) with a single wingdings character.

Comment: I guess one workaround I can try is copying the emoji from iOS into an email and setting them as the shortcut emoji to use in MS Outlook!  Only problem is it'll only work for me :(